# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me why I received the following error for the syntax below? Thanks.

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE STAFFDIR " +
                       "SET Last_Name = ?, " +
                       "SET First_Name = ?, " +
                       "SET Phone = ?, " +
                       "SET Dept_Code = ?, " +
                       "SET Email = ?, " +
                       "SET Title = ?, " +
                       "SET Loc_Code = ? " + 
                       "WHERE ID = ?;");

               stmt.setString(1, ID);
               stmt.setString(2, Last_Name);
               stmt.setString(3, First_Name);                   
               stmt.setString(4, Phone);
               stmt.setString(5, Dept_Code);
               stmt.setString(6, Email);
               stmt.setString(7, Title);
               stmt.setString(8, Loc_Code);
               stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You have the SET keyword on each line. Only keep the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update statement in Sql requires just one `SET` no matter how many fields are set, viz

```
UPDATE STAFFDIR SET Last_Name = ?,
                    First_Name = ?, -- No extra set
                    Phone = ?, ...
```

As an aside, are you using the correct driver (MS Access vs Sql Server)?

Comment: Yes, I am using Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/test.accdb");

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one SET. Do it as follows

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE STAFFDIR " +
                       "SET Last_Name = ?, " +
                       "First_Name = ?, " +
                       "Phone = ?, " +
                       "Dept_Code = ?, " +
                       "Email = ?, " +
                       "Title = ?, " +
                       "Loc_Code = ? " + 
                       "WHERE ID = ?;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query only needs one SET **and** you're binding the parameters in the incorrect order -

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE STAFFDIR " +
  "SET Last_Name = ?, First_Name = ?, Phone = ?, " +
  "Dept_Code = ?, Email = ?, Title = ?, Loc_Code = ? " + 
  "WHERE ID = ?");
int i = 1;
// stmt.setString(1, ID);
stmt.setString(i++, Last_Name);
stmt.setString(i++, First_Name);                   
stmt.setString(i++, Phone);
stmt.setString(i++, Dept_Code);
stmt.setString(i++, Email);
stmt.setString(i++, Title);
stmt.setString(i++, Loc_Code);
stmt.setString(i++, ID); // <-- the 8th field.
```

Also worth noting is that Java 8 removes the ODBC-JDBC bridge, so you might want to consider finding an alternative method of connecting to your DataSource.

Comment: In retrospect it hasn't actually done an update, it does nothing, but the syntax error is gone. Why would you have me move ID to the 8th position?

Comment: @user3511659 Because you *must* bind the parameters in the same order they are in your query.